# How to determine if code is getting executed as a function or using cell mode

Tags: debugging, matlab

I like to use [cell mode](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2011/07/26/starting-in-matlab-cell-mode-scripts/) rather than break points when writing/debugging functions.

How would you determine at run-time if the currently executing code is getting executed as a function or using cell mode?

**Bonus Points** If you can come up with a `function` that knows it is was invoked from within another function or from a cell.

An example of when this might be useful is when you want to load data differently during the execution of a function or if you want to create plotters for debugging.  It becomes a pain to comment out specific lines when switching between executing as a cell or a function.

```
function doSomethingAwesome(inputs)
%%

if executingAsCell == true
  clear
  importData
end


% process stuff

if executingAsCell == true
   plot(myAwesomeResults)
end
```

*Note, this is not a duplicate of my previous question:* [How to determine if code is executing as a script or function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443685/how-to-determine-if-code-is-executing-as-a-script-or-function)

Comment: +1 Interesting question. First thought (ugly hack): what about defining a dummy variable as the first thing you do in your function/script and then later check if it is defined?

Comment: You might be able to do this with [dbstack](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html), not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is using `dbstack()` as suggested by @Junuxx:

```
if isempty(dbstack)
   %# true if you evaluated the cell while not in debug mode
```

Similarly, a function can know whether it was invoked from another function or from base/cell by checking the length of the dbstack

```
   function doSomething
   if length(dbstack)==1
      %# the function has been invoked from a cell or the command line
      %# (unless you're in debug mode)
```

A function can actually distinguish whether it was invoked from command-line or from a cell, since the latter doesn't write into the history:

```
   function doSomething

   if length(dbstack)==1
      javaHistory=com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory;
      lastCommand = javaHistory(end).toCharArray'; % ' added for SO code highlighting
      if strfind(lastCommand,'doSomething')
         %#  Probably invoked via command line
      else
         %#  Probably invoked via executing a cell
```

If you want to determine whether you're in debug mode or not, one possibility is to use the `line`-argument from dbstack, and check whether there is a call to the currently executing function on the line the apparent calling function.

Comment: @Slayton: Thanks for the edit. Since I use the userscript provided by Amro (see tag wiki), I don't have code highlighting issues anymore